# How can I close an opened file after finishing using at the end of code execution in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am reading a word document inside a folder with vb.net, then I fill some data fields inside the document, after that I convert the word document into a pdf file and I save it in the same folder of my word document.

The problems becomes when I go to the folder where my word template is located, if I try to delete the word file, it shows me an error that say: "The document is been using by XML process", the only way to delete my file is killing the process  in the task manager, which is means after finishing executing the code, the word file is still opened.

I try to use at the end of the code: `Doc.Close()` but the compiler says that the sentences are ambiguous.

This is the code I am using:

```
Dim missing As Object = Type.Missing
Dim app As New Word.Application()
Dim doc As Word.Document=app.Documents.Open(Server.MapPath("~\\App_Tmp\\WordTemplate1.docx"), missing, True)
Dim fields As Word.FormFields = doc.FormFields
fields("tLegalName").Result = lawFirmObj.DisplayName
doc.Activate()
doc.SaveAs2(Server.MapPath("~\App_Tmp\Filled.pdf"), WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
```

Comment: this is not a `C#`

Comment: Looks like Visual Basic to me

Comment: Thanks, is in VB.net

Comment: try to call `Dispose` on `doc` and setting `doc` to `Null`

Comment: You need to disambiguate the call  - something like [`doc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.close.aspx) should do it. Note that the first parameter is whether you want to save changes. See [How to: Programmatically Close Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af6z0wa2.aspx).

Comment: Thanks men , it's work. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is very strange, now l am able to delete the word file, but in the task manager I still have "WINWORD32.EXE" process, and every time I run the code, an other instance of this process stacks, which is mean, at some point, it will get crack the memory on the computer.  Any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: I bumped into the answer,  I need to add this line at the end: app.Quit(False)